# No Such Element is found

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium to access data on the next page. For some reason, I can't get it to click submit on the web page: https://www.clarkcountycourts.us/Portal/Home/Dashboard/29

my code is as followed:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(20) # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds

driver.get("https://www.clarkcountycourts.us/Portal/Home/Dashboard/29")

search_box = driver.find_element_by_id("caseCriteria_SearchCriteria")
search_box.send_keys("Robinson")

WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name^='a-'][src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']"))).click()

submit_box = driver.find_element_by_id("btnSSSubmit").click()
```

I get the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="btnSSSubmit"]"}
```

for the last line of code submitting any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

the button elements are as followed:

```
<input name="Search" id="btnSSSubmit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Submit" type="submit">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are switching into the iframe and accessing an element inside it.
But the submit button is not inside that iframe, so to continue with elements out of that iframe you have to switch to the default content.
This should work better:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(20) # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds

driver.get("https://www.clarkcountycourts.us/Portal/Home/Dashboard/29")

search_box = driver.find_element_by_id("caseCriteria_SearchCriteria")
search_box.send_keys("Robinson")

WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name^='a-'][src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']"))).click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()

submit_box = driver.find_element_by_id("btnSSSubmit").click()
```

Comment: what is the possible solution of captcha? It seems that the resulting page is different when the captcha is filled as compared to when it is not filled. I think that the reason of above error is the appearance of captcha window. `driver.switch_to.default_content()` allows to focus on main window, instead of the captcha window. What do you think? Please explain.

Comment: I never actually dealt with captchas, so here I just assumed that since there were no problems with `WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']"))).click()` - that code line worked. Now, since we finished with elements inside the iframe and going to access elements out of the iframe - we have to get out from the iframe. Similarly to any other case we go into the iframe and get out of it to continue with regular content elements.